# Метод contains() используется на коллекцию полученную после Laravel метода map()

Tags: php, laravel

Объясните пожалуйста метод `contains()` который используется на коллекцию полученную после Laravel метода `map()` действует неправильно

После  использования метода map()  получаю коллекцию

```
Collection {#962 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
  "firstPatient" => "10:00"
  "secondPatient" => "18:00"
  ]
}
```

Затем нужно проверить есть ли заданное время в коллекции, для этого использую 
метод contains()

```
$myCollection->contains('10:00');
```

На что вместо ожидаемого true;
Выводится ошыбка

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function getKey() on string

Конструирую туже коллекцию **вручную**  и использую contains()

```
collect(['firstPatient' => '10:00', 'secondPatient' => '18:00'])
       ->contains('10:00');
```

О чудо, получаю долгожданный

> true

Еще более удивительно  то, что код

```
     `collect($myCollection->toArray())->contains('10:00')`
```

> Тоже true

---

Почему метод contains() выводит ошибку, когда использую его на  коллекцию полученную после использования метода map() ?

Добавлю что моя вручную созданная коллекция и коллекция полученная после метода map() идентичны.

```
dd($customCollection->toArray() === $collectionAfterMap->toArray())
```

> true

Comment: А как вы получаете первую коллекцию, с которой у вас проблема?

Comment: Получаю путем перебора Модели

Comment: Думаю это  баг  Laravel  5.6 23

Comment: Перешагнул проблему путем   `collect ( $collectionAfterMap ) -> contains( '10:00' )`    но вопросы остались